# Azure service bus transaction.Complete does not return

Tags: c#, azureservicebus

I'm making a little tool so that our admins can rerun faults. The mechanics are.
They first peek 100 messages then they can select and edit message and then send.

Problem is for some reason transaction.Complete never returns but I can see that the transaction indeed is commited becasue the message is moved from the error queue to the actual queue

```
public ServiceBus(IConfiguration config)
{

    var options = new ServiceBusClientOptions { EnableCrossEntityTransactions = true };
    _client = new(config["ServiceBus"], options);

    _queues = config.GetSection("Queues").Get<string[]>()!.Select(q => new Queue(q, _client.CreateReceiver($"{q}_error"), _client.CreateSender(q))).ToList();
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<Message>> PeekMessages()
{
    return (await _source.PeekMessagesAsync(100))
        .Select(m => new Message(m));
}


public async Task ResendMessages(IEnumerable<ResendableMessage> messages)
{
    using var ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled);
    var lookup = messages.ToDictionary(m => m.Seq);

    var lockedMessages = await _source.ReceiveMessagesAsync(1000); //TODO: not good can miss messages, fix later
    
    foreach (var lockedMessage in lockedMessages)
    {
        if (lookup.TryGetValue(lockedMessage.SequenceNumber, out var orginalMessage))
        {
            var send = new ServiceBusMessage(orginalMessage.Message);
            if (orginalMessage.Content != null)
                send.Body = new BinaryData(orginalMessage.Content);

            await _source.CompleteMessageAsync(lockedMessage);
            await _destination.SendMessageAsync(send);
        }
        else
            await _source.AbandonMessageAsync(lockedMessage);
    }

    ts.Complete(); //Halts here
}
```

edit: This doesnt work either

```
public async Task ResendMessages(IEnumerable<ResendableMessage> messages)
{
    await using var source = CreateSource();
    await using var destination = CreateDestination();
    
    var lookup = messages.ToDictionary(m => m.Seq);

    var lockedMessages = await source.ReceiveMessagesAsync(1000); //TODO: not good can miss messages, fix later

    foreach (var lockedMessage in lockedMessages)
    {
        using var ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled);

        if (lookup.TryGetValue(lockedMessage.SequenceNumber, out var orginalMessage))
        {
            var send = new ServiceBusMessage(orginalMessage.Message);
            if (orginalMessage.Content != null)
                send.Body = new BinaryData(orginalMessage.Content);

            await source.CompleteMessageAsync(lockedMessage);
            await destination.SendMessageAsync(send);
        }
        else
            await source.AbandonMessageAsync(lockedMessage);


        ts.Complete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A transaction in Azure Service Bus operates on a single recieved message. In your case you have a single transaction used for multiple received messages. Switch to a transaction per per received message

Comment: Thats what I tried first. See update for that version. No difference in outcome

Comment: I found the problem. It was a problem with WPF and async await. The application didnt liked when I ran the code from a button click. Strange. Moved it to a Task.Run and it works

Comment: Nice. So a single wrapping transactional scope works for all those messages? I suppose it could as all incoming messages are from the same queue and all the outgoing messages will be staged under it. Just wasn't aware that it's possible. Something new every day 

Comment: Yepp works fine. Only problem seems to be with async/await inside the desktop app. Interesting. :D

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with WPF or alternative with Caliburn micro. This didnt work

```
yield return _queue.ResendMessages(messages.Select(m => m.GetSendModel()).ToList()).AsResult();
```

But this did work

```
yield return Task.Run(() => _queue.ResendMessages(messages.Select(m => m.GetSendModel()).ToList())).AsResult();
```